# Start activity from fragment, then get callback

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to get a callback from an activity that I am starting with an intent in my fragment.

I thought I could do this with onActivityResult but it doesn't seem to get called when I `finish();` on the activity. Is this possible in a fragment?

*Fragment.java*

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getActivity().setTitle("Waiver");
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.waiver_layout, container, false);

    signBtn = myView.findViewById(R.id.signBtn);

    signBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SignatureActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("signatureAbleId", device.id);
            intent.putExtra("signatureAbleType", "App\\Models\\Device");

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return myView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    Log.v("Activity", "The activity has finished");

    if(resultCode == 200){
        saveWaiver();
    }
}

private void saveWaiver(){
    Log.v("Save Waiver", "Saving waiver for you.");
}
```

*SignatureActivity.java*

```
public class SignatureActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnClear;

    private Button btnSave;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signature);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(bundle != null){
            signatureAbleId = bundle.getInt("signatureAbleId");
            signatureAbleType = bundle.getString("signatureAbleType");
        }

        btnClear = findViewById(R.id.btnClear);

        btnSave = findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

        btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSignaturePad.clear();
            }
        });

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            setResult(200);

            finish();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Knew it was a stilly question, see answer for what I should have done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 11);

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode == 11){
        if(resultCode == 200){
            saveWaiver();
        }
    }else{
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this. It will help you

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SignatureActivity.class);
```

Instead of

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SignatureActivity.class);
```

And Yes need to change :

startActivity to startActivityForResult

Comment: Why would you use `getContect()`?

Comment: if use getActivity so call back will transfer to your parent activity onActivityResult method because during startActivityResult you are passing reference of your parent activity.
here you need to pass getContext() method through current context so callback will come to your fragment instead of parent activity.
I hope you get my point.